# Unable to receive test events through the Facebook Conversion API

Tags: facebook

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "event_name": "ViewContent",
            "event_time": 1620216748,
            "action_source": "email",
            "user_data": {
                "em": "7b17fb0bd173f625b58636fb796407c22b3d16fc78302d79f0fd30c2fc2fc068",
                "ph": null
            },
            "custom_data": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "value": "142.52"
            }
        }
    ],
      "test_event_code": "TEST1234"
}
```

I am using the test JSON request, it does not throw error and gives

```
{
  "events_received": 1,
  "messages": [
  ],
  "fbtrace_id": "As1JpX8LxeVtLP5XLSfY7Np"
}
```

But i am unable to get it under Facebook Event manager test events.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert this Json code:
You need only change the values of `<A IP ADDRESS>` and `<YOUR TEST_CODE>` with your data.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "event_name": "Purchase",
      "event_time": 1620921176,
      "action_source": "website",
      "user_data": {
        "em": "7b17fb0bd173f625b58636fb796407c22b3d16fc78302d79f0fd30c2fc2fc068",
        "client_user_agent": "mozilla",
        "client_ip_address": "<A IP ADDRESS>"
      },
      "custom_data": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": "142.52"
      }
    }
  ],
    "test_event_code": "<YOUR TEST_CODE>"
}
```

On my tests, it works after I insert these data:

```
"client_user_agent": "mozilla",
"client_ip_address": "<A IP ADDRESS>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to figure it out... I have tried quite a few things.  Entering the IP did the trick.  Not sure if that means there is something wrong, but I do know the conversation api test didn't work until we added the IP.